# MongoDB Exclude docs from aggregate if field/reference exists in other collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

```
const sellerSchema = Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    url:String
  }
```

```
const productSchema = Schema(
  {
    title: String,
    sellerUrl:String
  }
```

Below query will return unique `sellerUrl` from all products:

```
context.Product.aggregate([
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$sellerUrl",
          }
        }
      ]);
```

But I also want to exclude from aggregation, sellers that I already saved. So if `url == sellerUrl` aggregation must exclude that seller.
 Please help me

Comment: After group stage you'll get an array of unique seller's url from `Product` collection, Do you mean if that seller exists in `seller` collection then that seller's url should be removed from array result of above aggregation ? Also this grouping on unique urls only works if `sellerUrl` is like `amazon.com` but not like `amazon.com/car` & `amazon.com/truck`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below query :

```
db.product.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "", /** group on no condition & push all unique `sellerUrl` to sellerUrls array */
        sellerUrls: { $addToSet: "$sellerUrl" }
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "seller",
        let: { sellerUrls: "$sellerUrls" }, // creating local variable
        pipeline: [
          { $group: { _id: "", urls: { $addToSet: "$url" } } }, /** group on no condition & push all unique `url` to urls array */
          { $project: { _id: 0, uniqueAndNotInSellerColl: { $setDifference: [ "$$sellerUrls", "$urls" ] } } } // get difference between two arrays
        ],
        as: "data" // As we're grouping will always be one doc/element in an array
      }
    },
    /** Create a new root doc from getting first element(though it will have only one) from `data` array */
    {
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$data", 0 ] } }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AvrU5W-OHQ5)

**Update :**

As you need few other fields from `product` collection but not just the `sellerUrl` field then try below query :

```
db.product.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$sellerUrl",
        docs: { $push: { title: "$title" } } // We're only retrieving `title` field from `product` docs, if every field is needed use `$$ROOT`
      }
    },
    /** We've used basic `lookup` stage, use this if you've only few matching docs from `seller` collection
     *  If you've a lot of matching docs for each `_id` (sellerUrl), 
     *  then instead of getting entire `seller` doc (which is not needed) use `lookup` with aggregation pipeline & 
     *  just get `_id`'s of seller docs for better performace refer previous query
     */
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "seller",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "url",
        as: "sellerDocs"
      }
    },
    /** match will retain only docs which doesn't have a matching doc in seller collection */
    {
      $match: { sellerDocs: [] }
    },
    {
      $project: { sellerDocs: 0 }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RFbbaiFkCRq)

Comment: Yes, this is what i want, but instead of simple array i want to return an array of objects because i return more fields from `Product`. In example i just simplifed the schema

Comment: @MikeWill : Please do not do that, You need present complete request & response or all the scenarios needed, as this new requirement completely changes the way aggregation has to written, nothing here which is already done doesn't help !! Let me try to update my answer..

Comment: @MikeWill : Is this something that you're looking for : https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z_riVG0Xh8L ? If you can give me complete req and response needed, maybe I can update this query better.

Comment: I understand, never will do again. Yes this is almost, but seller with url `mongo.com` appears 2 times, i will try to solve this

Comment: @MikeWill : thanks for accepting, but I can help if needed, check out my updated answer ..

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z_riVG0Xh8L this works fine, but the `mongo.com` appears 2 times in result, it needs to be unique (only 1 time)

Comment: @MikeWill : Yes, I've updated the same-thing in my answer. Which output structure looks good https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z_riVG0Xh8L or https://mongoplayground.net/p/RFbbaiFkCRq ? It appears twice because of two different documents exists with `mongo.com`, if you need only one then instead of `$push` use `$first` or `$last`..